# Using Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS with MS-Access JDBC-ODBC throws exception

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

```
import java.sql.* ;
import java.util.* ;
import java.io.* ;

class DataBaseFactory{
    public static Connection getConnection() {
        // ...
    }
}

class Demo{
    public static void main(String []args) throws SQLException {
        Connection con = DataBaseFactory.getConnection() ;

        // This is throwing exception
        // PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into user values(?,?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS) ;

        // But this is working fine
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into user values(?,?)") ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249600/return-generated-keys-doesnt-work-using-jdbc-odbc/2252196#2252196

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the database driver you're using does not support RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS. What is the database you're trying to connect to?

Comment: i am using Microsoft access (Type-1 driver).

Comment: That's probably the issue (I see you also posted this on the Sun forums, and received a similar reply there).

Comment: There is a method to find taht out: connection.getMetaData().supportsGetGeneratedKeys()

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC-ODBC Bridge is obsolete and has been removed from Java 8. Fortunately, we can use the free, open-source [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver to work with Access databases from Java, and UCanAccess supports `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`. For more information, see

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)