# RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS doesn't work using JDBC ODBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to get insert ID while after inserting some data in my database.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO ADI.DUMMY(dummy_data) VALUES('from database logger')";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
int extUptReturn = ps.executeUpdate(sql);
```

But I got this exception:

```
Java exception: ''java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException''; 
    thrown from class name: ''sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection'', method name: ''prepareStatement'', file: ''JdbcOdbcConnection.java'', line: '1762'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ODBC bridge driver doesn't support it. Nothing to do against. Either replace the driver or live with it. I would just use a **real** JDBC driver instead of the poorly-developed, feature-lacking, bug-rich Sun ODBC bridge driver. Almost all self-respected server based RDBMS vendors provides a fullworthy JDBC driver for download at their homepage. Just Google "[vendorname] jdbc driver download" to find it. Here's an overview:

- [MySQL JDBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)
- [PostgreSQL JDBC driver](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) (note: older versions didn't support generated keys as well).
- [Oracle JDBC driver](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/index.html) (note: older versions didn't support generated keys as well).
- [MSSQL JDBC driver](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=99B21B65-E98F-4A61-B811-19912601FDC9&displaylang=en) (or performancewise better, the [jTDS JDBC driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/))
- DB2 JDBC driver is hard to find in IBM's online forest, but it's usually already included in the `/java` folder of the DB2 installation.
- [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) driver for Microsoft Access databases (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)).

Comment: -1 for unnecessary Access bashing. The reason why there isn't a driver for it is not because it's not an RDBMS, but because it's not a server database engine and shouldn't be used as a data store in the contexts in which JDBC is in use. Of course, I'm one of thos who believes Java has no place on the client...

Comment: @David: I didn't bash Access, I bashed the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver.

Comment: You said Access "isn't a fullfledged RDBMS". That's bashing Access, period, end of statement, no ambiguities whatsoever, and is only true if you have a WRONG definition of RDMBS. You lessened the quality of your answer by including it. You could delete that phrase and it wouldn't change the advice you give one iota.

Comment: @David: I should indeed maybe have added "server" behind "RDBMS" to clarify the bit a bit more. Thank you for the nitpick and sorry that it wasn't clear to you at first glance.

Comment: Then you don't need RDBMS, just "Jet/ACE is not a database server". And I'm the first to suggest that it's probably not appropriate for most Java-based apps for that reason. That is, it's inappropriate not because it's not an RDBMS (for some definition of RDBMS), but that it's not a *server* database engine, as you say. Why not edit, and I'll back out my downvote.

Comment: BTW, it occurs to me that it may be possible to get to Jet/ACE data via the SQL Server driver, after having set up your Jet/ACE database as a linked server...

Comment: @David: There, I put "server based" in.

Comment: I tried to reverse my downvote based on your edit, but it's too old to allow me to do so. Thanks for taking the time to edit.

Comment: *"Only for MS-Access ... you'll be forced to stick to ODBC bridge driver"* - That is no longer true. [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) is a free, open-source, pure Java JDBC driver for Access databases, and it supports `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`. More details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390).

Answer (score 0):

MAy be the JDBC implementation could not be supporting the sepcific opration.
CHeck the JDBC driver used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example instead of `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`:

```
String[] returnId = { "BATCHID" };
String sql = "INSERT INTO BATCH (BATCHNAME) VALUES ('aaaaaaa')";
PreparedStatement statement = connection
        .prepareStatement(sql, returnId);
int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdate();

if (affectedRows == 0) {
    throw new SQLException("Creating user failed, no rows affected.");
}

try (ResultSet rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
    if (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
    }
    rs.close();

}
```

Where BRANCHID is the auto generated id